# how optimize CDN without using plugins

Tags: cdn

i need help for optimizing my wordpress website without using plugins incloding wp-total-cache or wp-super-cache.check this link
https://gtmetrix.com/reports/akhbartop.ir/fF37Flwa
my website needs otimize in **Use a Content Delivery Network (CDN)** and **Configure entity tags (ETags)**
also i cant use MAXCDN :) please offer another ways

Answer (score 1):

You get 94% / 87% so what seem to be the problem?

The only thing i can thing of is the 7.0s load time which is ok but a bit long..

I have also checked your website on [Google PageSpeed Insights](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fakhbartop.ir%2F) and the results warn't too bad.

1. You need better servers, fast servers
2. Try combining your JS files and codes and load them in the footer before the  tag ends.

**TIP:**
The only JS file you should keep in your header is the main jQuery JS

Comment: i still have problem with CDN my server is cloud and its good

Answer (score 1):

Here is one

```
// Defer parsing of JavaScript files.
function any_page_first_defer_javascripts ( $url ) {
    if ( FALSE === strpos( $url, '.js' ) ) {
       return $url;
    }
    return "$url' async='async";
}
add_filter( 'clean_url', 'any_page_first_defer_javascripts', 11, 1 );
```

Here is another one

```
// Remove Query strings from Static Resources. 
function any_page_first_remove_script_version( $src ){
    return add_query_arg( 'ver', false, $src );
}
add_filter( 'script_loader_src', 'any_page_first_remove_script_version', 15, 1 );
add_filter( 'style_loader_src', 'any_page_first__remove_script_version', 15, 1 );
```